# navigation bar animation hidden from the last to the first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in jquery and animations, and I need help to do this.
I've got a navigation bar in my website and it has 10 buttons (level 1), when one of them has been clicled the navigation bar has to hide the buttons from right to left, when all of them have been hidden, start to appear a new navigation bar (level 2) shown from the first button to the last. the level 2 can have more or less number of buttons.
to be more clear I have this:

1  2  3   4   5   6 
when I click 4 the bar has to do something like this

1  2  3   4   5   6

1  2  3   4   5

1  2  3   4

1  2  3

1  2

1

and the new navigation has the items of 4. (4 it's the parent and this level has the children)

4.1

4.1  4.2

4.1  4.2  4.3

4.1  4.2  4.3  4.4

4.1  4.2  4.3  4.4  4.5

Comment: You should show what you have did already, and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the HTML you used to build your menu, but basically you'll want to:

Bind a click handler to each menu item. You can do this in HTML or JS.

Once clicked, you need to determine which element was clicked. Then you can animate the menu out using a timed delay with the fadeOut function, with the final animation calling the function to animate the new menu in. Something like this:

```
$('#menu_5').fadeOut(300);
$('#menu_4').delay(100).fadeOut(300);
$('#menu_3').delay(200).fadeOut(300);
$('#menu_2').delay(300).fadeOut(300);
$('#menu_1').delay(400).fadeOut(300);
$('#menu_0').delay(500).fadeOut(300, function(){
  submenu_intro(selected_index);
});
```

You can animate in the same way. Some how, in this function, you'll have to have a way to load the submenu so you can animate it in. This is just a simple example of how the animation would work:

```
$('#menu_'+selected_index).fadeIn(300);
$('#menu_'+selected_index+'_submenu_0').delay(100).fadeIn(300);
$('#menu_'+selected_index+'_submenu_1').delay(200).fadeIn(300);
$('#menu_'+selected_index+'_submenu_2').delay(300).fadeIn(300);
$('#menu_'+selected_index+'_submenu_3').delay(400).fadeIn(300);
$('#menu_'+selected_index+'_submenu_4').delay(500).fadeIn(300);
```

NOTE: The way you are doing your navigation, there is no way to get back to the main navigation (level 1)!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is messy and can probably be improved, but I think it is what you are looking for. It will also depend on your setup.

http://jsfiddle.net/PL7an/2/